# Problems creating a project with CodenameOne in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, codenameone, netbeans-plugins

Install Netbeans 12.6 on a Windows 10 machine. I was able to install the CodenameOne plugin with no problem. When creating a project I get the following error message:

Cannot invoke "org.openide.filesystems.FileObject.getFileObject(String)" because "folder" is null
[image]
I've been surfing the internet and can't find a way to fix it.
Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is no longer supported. The plugin is only used for legacy applications and no longer works in newer IDEs due to breaking changes in almost all IDEs.

Starting with Codename One 7.x we moved to maven projects which don't require the plugin and can be created in https://start.codenameone.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the instructions in the manual and it mentions as important:

"Before opening the project in NetBeans, you need to copy the contents of the tools/netbeans directory into the root project directory. These files are required by NetBeans to build, run, and debug the project correctly. "

But I can't find this folder in netbeans version 12.6.
[image]